# Why won't a particular image show up on Safari iOS on an iPad 4?

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, background-image

I have a page with four different  tags enclosing some content. Each of the section tags has a background image.

The weird thing is that two of the backgrounds images (the second and fourth) show up, but the other two don't. First I tried replacing the images that wouldn't show up by re-uploading the background image. It still didn't show up. Next I tried making the size of the background image the same size (dimensions) as one of the working background images. This didn't work either. Next I tried using one of the other background images as the background images of the two sections that weren't showing their background image. This did show up!

So for some reason even though the image is the same size as another working image and even though the source image url works fine, these two images won't show up on an iPad.

This is a wordpress site, and I am posting the wordpress template code for those sections.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 4,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
?>

<?php $about_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if($about_query->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while($about_query->have_posts()): ?>

        <?php $about_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php $about_bg = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>

        <article class="about-section" style="background-image: url('<?= $about_bg; ?>');">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="about-content small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">

                    <h2 class="about-header">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h2>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's the CSS in question:

```
.about-section {
    @include background-size(cover); /* Compass Include */

    position: relative;
    height: 850px;
    min-height: 850px;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was some sort of corruption in the original image that was uploaded to Wordpress. I tried re-exporting it with different dimensions and had no luck. I tried re-uploading the image and also had no luck. Finally I tried re-exporting the image with a different file format and re-uploading it. This worked! Once I had re-exported it with a new file format, I was able to export it back to the original file format and the image worked. I can only assume that there was some kind of corruption in the original image that went away after it was converted to a different format.